# ¿Cómo aplicamos el pretérito pluscuamperfecto continuo?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Este tiempo lo considero de poco uso, pero al momento de aplicarlo, viene siendo así como *la ocasión* para aplicarlo.

Por ejemplo,

> *Yo estaba cansado. **Había estado jardineando**.*

Se acostumbra a usar más el pasado continuo,

> *Yo estaba cansado. **Estaba jardineando**.*

Pero ambas afirmaciones poseen significados distintos.
¿Qué tan usado es este tiempo verbal en otros lados? Yo lo uso acá en mi país pero muy rara vez.

Answer (score 1):

Se usa para referirse a una acción/proceso continuo que tuvo lugar antes que el pasado.

Usemos el ejemplo del libro de la respuesta anterior, e imagina que yo soy el que te  está diciendo.

> Por fin encontré un libro que había estado buscando hace rato.

El presente es el momento en el que yo te digo que encontré el libro.

El pasado es el momento cuando encontré el libro.

Un pasado mas lejano es el momento en el que estuve buscando el libro, "buscando el libro" fue una  acción continua (lo hice por media hora, una hora etc.).

Entonces buscar el libro ocurrió antes que encontrar el libro. Y para expresar eso en presente usas este tiempo verbal.

Otro ejemplo.

Cuando llegué a trabajar, mis compañeros ya habían estado trabajando toda la mañana.

En contra posición "Cuando llegué, mis compañeros ya estaban trabajando toda la mañana" suena raro.

En mi opinión si hablas en presente del pasado y un pasado mas lejano deberías usar el tiempo perfecto. Sin embargo y honestamente nunca me he puesto a analizar como es que hablo diariamente.

En cuanto al significado de

"Estaba cansado, estaba jardineando."

Tengo la impresión de que "estaba jardineando" se refiero al una accion inmediatamente anterior.

Y "había estado jardineando" no necesariamente se refiere al momento inmediato anterior, puede referirse a un momento en el pasado aun mas lejano.

Comment: Mi interpretación es de este estilo: usarlo para una acción que había estado en progreso antes de otra acción. Entonces para ponerlo en contexto — ***Estuve buscando** el libro toda la mañana pero encontré otros. Después lo volví a buscar y por fin encontré el libro que **había estado buscando.***

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que sí se usa. Como tú dices tiene significados distintos así que es difícil decirlo de otra forma.

Ahora durante el almuerzo presté atención a las conversaciones de mis colegas y lo escuché en esta oración:

> Por fin encontré un libro que había estado buscando hace rato.

Comment: Lo he visto para describir la causa de algo en el pasado. Es lo que me parece más sensato. Pero me gustaría saber si hay otro matiz.